# Lead-acid battery seems to be gaining capacity through use; why is this?

Tags: ups, lead-acid

I am testing an alternative battery cartridge for an APC 3000 VA UPS. It's an OEM cartridge, but with the OEM batteries removed and replaced with Duracell 12 V, 5 Ah SLA batteries by a third party.

I am comparing its performance to the OEM cartridge by stress-testing ("manual runtime calibration", I learned the manufacturer calls it). I let the unit charge the battery to 100%, and then disconnect power while the unit is powering a constant 920 W resistive load (a space heater). I measure the runtime until the device shuts off.

My first test ran for about 8 minutes. The first test was done with new batteries and no time spent charging.

My second test ran for 16:40. The battery was charged to 100% (about 4 hours).

My third test ran for 19:13. The battery was charged overnight (about 18 hours).

My fourth test ran for 18:52. The battery was charged to 100% (about 4 hours), same as the second test.

The UPS unit reported 100% battery before each test.

The results I expected are a runtime of about 26 minutes for the first test, with the general trend of slightly lower runtimes for subsequent tests possibly masked by random noise. The actual results are nearly the opposite. What could cause this?

Comment: A 12 volt 5 AH battery has 60 watt-hour capacity.  In perfect conditions it will run a 920W load for 60/920 of an hour or about 4 minutes.

Comment: This cartridge has 10 such batteries in it, wired in series.

Comment: Batteries may have had slight sulfation which will reduce the capacity of the batteries. Charge cycling can reduce sulfation.

Comment: The UPS probably has battery management to determine when the batteries are depleted. It may measure total watts drawn, battery voltage, and other parameters. Perhaps it "remembered" the capacity of the worn-out batteries -- cutting you off before the new capacity was fully used -- and is still learning the new ones.

Comment: I've gotten up to 25 minute runtime with OEM cartridges in this UPS unit before, and it prompts "New battery installed?" when changing the battery, which I assume would clear any saved memory of the old batteries.

Comment: If you keep doing that, you'll see deep cycle capacity decline. Lead acids are damaged by deep discharging.  They're really an awful design of battery, but they're so much cheaper than alternatives that they're still a win.  Actually, we're now at a tipping point where lithium is becoming cheaper in many deep cycle applications.

Comment: _"The results I expected are a runtime of about 26 minutes for the first test, with the general trend of slightly lower runtimes" - why did you expect this? Exactly which Duracell batteries are they?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I expected a 26 minute first run because that's what OEM batteries get, and I expect slightly lower runtimes after that because of wear on the battery.  They are Duracell SLAA12-5F2

Answer (score 1):

> The results I expected are a runtime of about 26 minutes for the first test, with the general trend of slightly lower runtimes for subsequent tests possibly masked by random noise. The actual results are nearly the opposite. What could cause this?

The UPS's idea of what "100% battery capacity is" is often unrealistic. In your case "often" means "always" :)

I'm sorry I don't have better news: some UPSes are notorious for poor capacity estimates.

> Lead acid battery seems to be gaining capacity

No. If you wanted to measure the battery capacity, you'd need an instrument to do so. UPS is not a laboratory tool to measure battery capacity. It's not even close.

All we can guess from your results is that the battery capacity didn't change much, but the UPS's idea of what it is has been steadily improving. If you plot it against the charge cycle #, you may notice an asymptote that would be a more realistic estimate of the battery capacity. Even then, though, the UPS is usually basing its behavior on rather simplistic battery models and the results bear that.